# Unexpected Error on committing changes when Talisman is setup for my repository

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com, talisman

I did a Talisman setup for my project repository and now I am unable to commit changes to a branch. It aborts with the following error. Please help!

```
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/thoughtworks/talisman.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('go', 'get', './...')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout:
    Executable `go` not found
stderr: (none)
```

Comment: The Talisman code is written in Go and installation requires that you first install a Go compiler.

Comment: Hi I did that but now I am getting another error

Comment: talisman.................................................................Failed
- hook id: talisman-commit
- exit code: 1

Executable `talisman` not found

Comment: That sounds like a `$PATH` issue, but I haven't experimented with Talisman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for whatever reason it looks like `talisman` incorrectly installs as an executable named `cmd` instead of `talisman` when installed from source

I would suggest sending a pull request to correct this code [here](https://github.com/thoughtworks/talisman) to use `entry: cmd --githook pre-commit` (as well as below in that file)

a workaround is to override the incorrect value directly in your configuration:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/thoughtworks/talisman
    rev: v1.22.0
    hooks:
    -   id: talisman-commit
        entry: cmd --githook pre-commit
```

this seems to have regressed at some point, perhaps during a refactor / reorganization of their code -- probably in [this commit](https://github.com/thoughtworks/talisman/commit/bf06fdd0ba73760112c3782fd3e6bb07d9273d42#diff-234338d9bfd18c4e1db576c296a3bc0dada925d5e81e4a8e55099b44fec11768)

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit